# Apache Camel Netty4 high memory usage

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

Am I doing something wrong in the code below?  Or is there some known issue with the netty4 component where it just has high memory usage?

My problem:

I'm using Camel's netty4 component to stream data from a socket, aggregate it and then send it on its way.

I've tried many different strategies for aggregating the data and nothing seems to have helped or hurt the memory usage.

I have an aggregation period of 30 seconds, and the data coming in totals about 1.3MB in that 30 seconds.

However, I notice that my memory usage is increasing by **4MB** every 30 seconds.  I'm using `watch free -m` in Linux to monitor the memory consumption.  There are no other processes running in the foreground except the terminal with the Camel process running.  The memory usage was entirely stable before running the Camel process (no fluctuations on the scale of MB).

I've played with just about every netty4 setting, provided by the Camel documentation, that was obvious to me and nothing seems to decrease the amount of memory being used.

I run the Camel instance from the command line using

```
java -Xms200M -Xmx275M -Xss512k -Drolling_log_dir=/logs/ -jar myCamel.jar
```

My route:

```
from( netty4:tcp://localhost:12345?clientMode=true&textline=true ).routeId( routeId + "A" )
    .log( LoggingLevel.INFO, rollingLogFile, "${body}" )
    .aggregate( constant(true), new StringAggregationStrategy(dataType) )
    .completionInterval( 30000 )
    .to( fileUri );

from( fileUri ).routeId( routeId + "B" )
    .process(doTheThing)
    .to( pushFile )
    .log( "Transferred ${file:name} complete" );
```

StringAggregationStrategy.java:

```
package com.aggregators;

import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Path; 
import java.nio.file.Paths; 
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange; 
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class StringAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy { 
    private static Path tempFileDir; 
    public StringAggregationStrategy(String dataType){ 
        tempFileDir = Paths.get("camelTempAggFileStorage/" + dataType + "/"); 
    }

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String exchangeId;
        Path tempAggFilePath;

        if (!Files.exists(tempFileDir)){
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(tempFileDir);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (oldExchange == null){
            cleanDirectory(tempFileDir);
            exchangeId = newExchange.getExchangeId();
            tempAggFilePath = Paths.get(tempFileDir.toString() + "/" + exchangeId + ".txt");
        } else{
            File oldFile = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
            tempAggFilePath = oldFile.toPath();
        }

        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempAggFilePath, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)){
            if (oldExchange == null) {
                writer.write(newBody);
                newExchange.getIn().setBody(tempAggFilePath.toFile());
                return newExchange;
            } else {
                writer.newLine();
                writer.write(newBody);
                oldExchange.getIn().setBody(tempAggFilePath.toFile());

                return oldExchange;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return oldExchange; 

    }

    private void cleanDirectory(Path tempFileDir) {
        for (File tempFile: tempFileDir.toFile().listFiles()){
            if (!tempFile.isDirectory()){
                tempFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Using VisualVM and monitoring the goings-on of the application, it seems that Netty starts spawning extra threads when something like a Broken Pipe exception occurs, but those never get cleaned up.  When taking a look at my heap dump after 17 hours of my Java program running, I see that the biggest offenders (number of instances of the class) are `io.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle` and `io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer$Entry` at 20.2% (59,630) and 19.8% (58,306) of the classes in my heap respectively.

Any ideas on how Camel can mitigate these settings?

Comment: "my memory usage is increasing by 4MB every 30 seconds." -- as measured how?

Comment: ah sorry, i explained everything else but that.. haha. I have everything closed down except the terminal with the Java process and I'm watching the `free -m` command in Linux.  The memory is in a stable state before I run the process, so I know nothing else is using up memory at the same time.  I should update the question

Comment: 1.3MB on disk could potentially result in 4MB when loaded into memory because of compression etc. So, every 30 seconds you are aggregating the incoming data into a file which is then persisted in memory. The reason why the memory is increasing could be that the file is either not deleted from memory when the processing is finished or that the GC simply doesn't kick in until it is needed. What happens if you just append the incoming data to your exchange body instead of creating a File?

Comment: @noMad17 We had previously appended the incoming data to the exchange's body, and still the same results.  I even through a `System.gc()` into the code to see if I can make the garbage collector jump in.  It seemed to have no effect on the memory being used.

Comment: Ok, what is happening in the `.to( pushFile )`? Is it actually a call to the file-component or are you doing something in there that could result in the file being kept in memory?

Comment: @noMad17 it's a call to the file component.  Basically what's happening is we're taking the aggregated file and putting it into a directory.  Then the 2nd half of the route is taking it from that directory and pushing it elsewhere using another file component... I forgot to mock up the part where the 2nd half of the route does some extra processing.  Oops.  Basically there's no reason a file should stick around in memory. All the moving of the file is done locally

Comment: Hmm, yes, I agree. Would it be possible for you to try fetching the same data using a different component? Perhaps downloading via ftp just to make sure that the issue is with the netty4-component and not somewhere else?

Comment: @noMad17 I can't do that, it's data that's streamed through a socket and socket only

Comment: Another possible test could be to skip the aggregation and processing and just append to a single file. I know this is not what you are trying to achieve but it could give an indication as to where the issue is. Since you see an increase every 30 seconds which coincides with the aggregation I think it's too early to blame netty.

Answer (score 2):

Java will claim as much memory as it likes, up to the configured limits.

Even when GC clears away objects , which it will only do when almost full, it usually won't return the memory it has claimed to the OS. It will keep the chunk it has `malloc()`d for future objects.

Therefore you would expect almost any Java program that's creating a lot of new objects (even if they are short-lived) to keep claiming memory until its heap reaches the size specified by `-Xmx`.

Hotspot does its own memory management -- that is, it `malloc()`s big blocks, and uses them as it wishes, rather than doing a `malloc()` every time it creates an object.

Therefore `free` is not a great tool for seeing whether a Java program is behaving itself.

To see inside the JVM memory, use a tool such as VisualVM - you can then watch the heap size, object count, etc. If your program really is leaking memory, you'll see it here.

If you want your Java program to use less memory, set `-Xmx` lower, which will force GC to work in a smaller allocation of memory.